# JQuery : "event.preventDefault()" won't work for dynamically created elements ...?

Tags: jquery, events, dynamically-generated

I add some input fields dynamically (all have a "addToQuantityTotal_1" Class name)
and want the user to only be able to type numbers inside.

So i use the "on" keyword (because that's the only way it worked with elements that i've created after the page finished loading) and everything works fine, except :
"event.preventDefault()"

It identifies that the user press non-numeric key, but still it add it to the input field.

```
$('body').on('keydown', 'input.addToQuantityTotal_1', function() {
    alert("keyCode = " + event.keyCode);
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || 
         // Allow: Ctrl+A
        (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) || 
         // Allow: home, end, left, right
        (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105 )) {
            alert("this is NOT a number!");
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: you miss `event` parameter on function parameters `$('body').on('keydown', 'input.addToQuantityTotal_1', function(event) {`

Comment: What about checking your console next time???

Comment: How does it identify non-numeric key presses without the event parameter???

Comment: It works in chrome as the event object is available, but will fail in Firefox as it has to be passed in explicitly

Comment: @Sushanth-- Well I never - thanks for that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`event` is not defined. It should be `function(event) {...`

Comment: Thanks Daniel & slash197,
You both helped :)